# Is there a name for for this "stateful function with result" pattern? An abstraction for it in FSharpPlus?

Tags: f#, f#+

I have a function of type `'state -> 'event -> Result<'state * 'result, 'error>`.  I have a starting `'state` and `'event list`.

I'd like to fold over the events and get the final state and list of results produced if all folds were okay, or the first error.

I could write a computation expression or fold for it, but was wondering if there was a name for this pattern?  Is there something I could use out-of-the-box from FSharpPlus?  It seems close to a state monad, but the state and result are both wrapped inside a `Result` type, so it's sort of a state + result monad?

Comment: If you can flip the first two arguments then this would be more or less (in *Haskell-Lingo*) `event -> StateT state (Except error result)` - so a `StateT s` wrapper around Except - AFAIK this is available in FsharpPlus (PS: yes Except = Result here - there is a `ResultT` *transformer* as well but I'm sure the *Result*-Monad is included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @carsten already pointed, you have `StateT` available in F#+

You have:

`'state -> 'event -> Result<'state * 'result, 'error>`

Now let's swap some parameters:

`'event -> 'state -> Result<'result * 'state, 'error>`

this can be expressed as

`StateT<'state, Result<'result * 'state, 'error>` in current F#+ StateT encoding.

So, let's call your function `f` and let's pretend you have `events` which is an `list<'event>` (or actually any other traversable structure of events)  , now you can do this:

```
#r "nuget: FSharpPlus, 1.2"
open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

// your code for 'f', 'events' and `initialState` definition goes here

let foldedStateT : StateT<'state, Result<'result * 'state, 'error> =
    events |> traverse (fun x -> StateT (f x))

let finalResult = StateT.run foldedStateT initialState
```

Comment: Thanks!  Why does `StateT` know how to unwrap a `Result`?  I would have thought they were unrelated concepts.  Hard to guess this is built-in from the docs, too.

Comment: It doesn't really know how. As any other monad transformer, it relies on the `bind` and `return` implementation of the wrapped monad (Result in this case). As an interesting exercise, try changing `Result<_,_>` to `Choice<_,_>` or `Option<_>`.